# OCR extraction from scans

Tags: ocr, text-processing

I really need your help!

I have been tasked by my university to digitise a whole bunch of historical data. These are old scans from books and my task would be to copy the data by hand.

Since this task annoys me a lot, I was wondering if I could use OCR in Python that would extract the data and create a csv file. In the meantime I have encountered the problem that

1. sometimes bad readability of the numbers
2. table lines are seen as characters: / ( )
   By now I have tried Onenote character extraction and Excel 'read from image'. Both didn't go well.

So I'm wondering if anyone can recommend a package specifically for this data, or if you have tips and tricks for this task that would otherwise take me weeks.

One example of the scans:
[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting this to OCR direct to data will be likely next to impossible. The numbers are skewed, and the graphic components are inconsistent. So since this will take informed and willful processing, outside a human overlooking and cleaning, *Maybe* AI driven OCR https://cloud.google.com/use-cases/ocr could get you closer to "what you meant" vs "what was literal"

They have a free trial, may be worth a look.

Other than an AI driven solution, a temp typing, or maybe proofreading imperfect OCR scans. will probably be the only real solution.

Example this is the best I could get tesseract to do.

> 1 922 1 299
>
> 1 028 1 568
>
> 1 828
>
> 2 085 1771
>
> 1 205
>
> 2 147 1173
>
> 2 347 1 489 2 846
>
> 1 620 1 763 646
>
> 1579
>
> 693 519 466
>
> 317
>
> 816 817 2 364
>
> 1 182 1 054
>
> 869 2 958 1 201 1 049
>
> 816
>
> 81
>
> 151
>
> 18 10
>
> 0 21
>
> j9Sbm.png (958x756)
>
> 1515
>
> 1730 1 152,
>
> 872. 141 1)
>
> 1 688 | 1 800! 1 448) H |
>
> 1 006) 764! 233 |
>
> 1 843| 1 130;
>
> i 2 042) 1 264) 2 593)
>
> 1 396
>
> 561 1 37
>
> 623 566 41% He 34 mm
>
> 6. i 721
>
> 1 964) 1 05: 934

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the effort. I will have a look at the tool! Could you provide your code? That would maybe give me a hint on how to write my own code.

Comment: Was not code, it was just playing with options in tesseract trying to get any output that looked anything like the desired outcome, never really got close.